# RestSharp deserialization with 2 arrays

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have a json response that I am trying to deserialize with RestSharp
This is how it looks

```
[{"cname":"APPLICANT NAME","dob":"01-01-1997","gender":"2","msg":"Ok","msgcode":"0"},
{"results":
[{"subjectcode":"214","subject":"SOCIAL STUDIES","grade":"C5"},
{"subjectcode":"302","subject":"ENGLISH LANG","grade":"C5"},
{"subjectcode":"402","subject":"MATHEMATICS(CORE)","grade":"E8"},
{"subjectcode":"517","subject":"INTEGRATED SCIENCE","grade":"D7"},
{"subjectcode":"203","subject":"ECONOMICS","grade":"D7"},
{"subjectcode":"204","subject":"GEOGRAPHY","grade":"B3"},
{"subjectcode":"205","subject":"GOVERNMENT","grade":"C6"},
{"subjectcode":"207","subject":"HISTORY","grade":"B3"}]
}]
```

I have  created these classes to help me serialize

```
public class Result
{
    public string subjectcode { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public string grade { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDetail
{
    public string cname { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public string msgcode { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

public class VerifyData
{
    public List<StudentDetail> StudentDetails { get; set; }
}
```

However whenever I try to deserialize with RestSharp

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute<VerifyData>(request);
```

I get the following error message:

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'RestSharp.JsonArray' to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."}

Any pointers, have searched similar questions but was not able to fix this.
Thanks

Json data now is

```
[{"cname":"APPLICANT NAME","dob":"01-01-1997","gender":"2","msg":"Ok","msgcode":"0",
"results":
[{"subjectcode":"214","subject":"SOCIAL STUDIES","grade":"C5"},
{"subjectcode":"302","subject":"ENGLISH LANG","grade":"C5"},
{"subjectcode":"402","subject":"MATHEMATICS(CORE)","grade":"E8"},
{"subjectcode":"517","subject":"INTEGRATED SCIENCE","grade":"D7"},
{"subjectcode":"203","subject":"ECONOMICS","grade":"D7"},
{"subjectcode":"204","subject":"GEOGRAPHY","grade":"B3"},
{"subjectcode":"205","subject":"GOVERNMENT","grade":"C6"},
{"subjectcode":"207","subject":"HISTORY","grade":"B3"}]
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the extra class `VerifyData`. That you need is the following:

```
var studentDetails = client.Execute<StudentDetail>(request).Data;
```

or in two steps:

```
var response = client.Execute<StudentDetail>(request);
var studentDetails = response.Data;
```

**UPDATE**

Using `JsonConvert` (Json.NET), if you defined the following classes:

```
public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("subjectcode")]
    public string Subjectcode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("grade")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

public class StudentDetail
{
    [JsonProperty("cname")]
    public string Cname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dob")]
    public string Dob { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("msg")]
    public string Msg { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("msgcode")]
    public string Msgcode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public IList<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

You can try the following one:

```
JsonConvert.Deserialize<StudentDetail>(json)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Just tried your suggestion and it returns null

Comment: @Tonto You are welcome. Have you added this `client.AddHandler("application/json", () => new RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());` for your client ? This should be done before we call the `Execute` method.

Comment: thanks for your time. I am unable to add the line you suggested without an error. I am playing around with `JsonConvert.Deserialize` as well and this seems to give some results. If I do `JsonConvert.Deserialize<StudentDetail>(json)` it gives me an error. But if i do `JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<StudentDetail>(json)` the serialization is done but return 2 items instead of just 1

Comment: ok,  this `JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<StudentDetail>>(json)` gives me the correct data now. The json was not properly formed earlier so we had to talk with the API designers about it. Now I ended up with this which works `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentDetail>>(jsonContent)`